# D3: Graph doesn't display the x and y axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have this d3 project but I can't seem to display my x and y axis properly. It only displays the first 2 numbers on the y axis and that's it. Can anybody help me why it is not displaying. What am I missing here?

this is the code:

```
loadData = ()=> {
  req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json" , true);
  req.send();
  req.onload= ()=>{
      json = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
      //create measurements
      const margin = 60
      const width = 1000 - margin;
      const height = 600 - margin;

      //create svg
      const svg = d3.select("svg");
      const chart = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin}, ${margin})`);


      //y-axis: split charts into 2 equal parts using scaling function
      const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .range([height, 0]) //length
        .domain([0,100]); //content

      //create x-axis
      const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);

      //append y-axis
      chart.append("g")
        .call(yAxis);

       //create x-scale
      const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
        .range([0, width]) //length
        .domain([0,100]) //content
        .padding(0.2);

      //create x-axis
      const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

      //append x-axis
      chart.append("g")
        .attr(`transform`, `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(xAxis);
   } 
}

loadData();
```

This is my codepen:
[codepen](https://codepen.io/roger1891/pen/rRxRRz?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with a pane size of w1000, h600 (+margin). Size your SVG element (in CSS) accordingly, and the chart will show as expected:

```
svg {
  width: 1030px;
  height: 630px;
}
```

PS: Alternatively set the svg size in your JS code, thus you have to define those numbers only in one place.